# How to pass a rid as an argument to a custom sql function in OrientDB?

Tags: function, arguments, orientdb

I'm trying to create a custom sql function in the OrientDB Studio that takes a rid as an argument and, let's say, selects from that rid. The problem is that when I pass a rid it is not recognised as a rid inside the function, but as an argument of the string type. Does anyone know how to convert it to an actual rid so I can select or traverse from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if it is a string inside your function like this

```
var graph = orient.getGraph()
return graph.command('sql',"select from " +rid );
```

with rid as parameter of the function

Comment: That's how I can do it in a javascript function. But I wonder how to do the same thing in an sql function. I know that I can access an argument inside the function by preceding the corresponding parameter name with the $ sign. So if rid is the parameter's name, I can do something like that  ```select $rid```. The value of the $rid is taken as a string here, not as the actual rid. But how can I make the following query ```select from $rid``` work?

Comment: I'm afraid that you have to stick with javascript functions.
I've checked and is not supported parameters in the query target

Comment: Ensure you check the rid for sql injection. Or use prepared queries.